# Why does Affectiva SDK give more than one feature in a second?

Tags: affdex-sdk

I downloaded sample affectiva cpp sdk examples from https://github.com/Affectiva/cpp-sdk-samples
I am using video-demo and it gives a csv file. 
I would like to understand TimeStamp changes in this csv file. Why does it give more than one feature in a second? What is the logic behind it? How does it work?
Could you please explain?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Output from the Affectiva SDK is unique by time stamp and face ID.  So in the event that there are multiple identical time stamps, the sdk probably saw multiple faces at that moment.
you should also get output for each of the metrics, for each face, for each frame
https://developer.affectiva.com/metrics/

Comment: Thank you, Matt for the answer. Yes, I get all 52 features in at the time stamp. Even if it detects only one person it still gives more features in a second. Is it like whenever it detects any expression it gives as a feature?  As an example: 
>TimeStamp faceId interocularDistance glasses age  
>2018-01-25 11:52 1 62,0428 no 35-44
>2018-01-25 11:52 1 60,0165 no 35-44
>2018-01-25 11:52 1 58,2964 no 35-44
>2018-01-25 11:52 1 59,1436 no 35-44
>2018-01-25 11:52 1 58,9606 no 35-44

Comment: I suspect the SDK is sampling more than once a minute. I see "2018-01-25 11:52" for timestamp. The SDK measures for each frame in the video feed.